# How do I find out what processes are accessing the hard disk in a GNU/Linux-based system?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, process, io, resource-usage

I'm looking for the equivalent to **top** for disk access, so I can tell which process(es) are currently reading and/or writing to disk.  I'm currently using Ubuntu, but I imagine there's a standard tool that's available as part of the GNU toolset.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You got three-fifths of the answer right yourself - the one you want is called [iotop](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/). Search for it in the extra repositories, it should be there.

[image]

Comment: +1 beat me to it.  here's the project homepage: http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/

Comment: There's an **iotop** package in the **universe** repository available since Ubuntu 8.10 (Intrepid Ibex), so a `sudo apt-get install iotop` should do it.

Answer (score 33):

`htop` » <kbd>F2</kbd> » Columns » Active Columns » `IO_RATE`

Then sort by this column. Also you can add `IO_READ_RATE` and `IO_WRITE_RATE` columns and sort according to them.

Comment: This worked for me on the embedded Linux in a Synology box (where installing other packages isn't really an option)

Answer (score 11):

`iotop` is the counterpart to `top` that watches I/O usage information. If you want detailed information on the files opened by a process, or the list of files opened in a directory, or watch over files in the whole system, use `lsof`.`lsof` is quite versatile and provides information about open tcp, udp, NFS connections too.

Answer (score 6):

I use [atop](http://www.atoptool.nl/).

> Atop is an ASCII full-screen performance monitor that is capable of
>   reporting the activity of all processes (even if processes have
>   finished during the interval), daily logging of system and process
>   activity for long-term analysis, highlighting overloaded system
>   resources by using colors, etc. At regular intervals, it shows
>   system-level activity related to the CPU, memory, swap, **disks** and
>   network layers, and for every active process it shows the CPU
>   utilization, memory growth, **disk utilization**, priority, username,
>   state, and exit code.

[image]